# DAE world dosnt load in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, world, dae, launch

I am struggling to load my dae world in gazebo using a launch file.

I have a dae file containing an apartment called `apartment.dae`.
I have a simple world file called `apartment.world` calling the dae file, like shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sdf version="1.4">
  <world name="default">
    <include>
      <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
      <uri>model://sun</uri>
    </include>
    <model name="my_mesh">
      <pose>0 0 0  1.5708 0 0</pose>
      <static>true</static>
      <link name="body">
        <visual name="visual">
          <geometry>
            <mesh><uri>file://apartment.dae</uri></mesh>
          </geometry>
        </visual>
      </link>
    </model>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

When I call the world using `gazebo apartment.world` everything works fine.

Now I want a launch file like the following the launch my .world and with it my .dae.

```
<launch>
  <!-- We resume the logic in empty_world.launch, changing only the name of the world to be launched -->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find buildon_main)/apartment.world"/> 
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    <arg name="recording" value="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
  </include>
</launch>
```

But all I get is an empty world.

I'm pretty sure, to know the problem, but I can't solve it. I think when the launch file takes the `apartment.world` it tries to find the `apartment.dae` in it in relation to the `gazebo_ros` package. Obviously without success.
But now I don't know how to give it the right path, since the .world file doesn't seem to have a function like the `$(find gazebo_ros)` in the launch file.

I am grateful for any advice or if someone could lead me in the right direction.
Best regards!
Elias